# Swift SpriteKit Multiple Nodes in Scene with same Condition

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, swift4

I have multiple spritenodes in the Scene with the same Name. If I want to edit them all in the .swift file, just one reacts to the conditions and all of the other Nodes stays like in the scene.
For example if I want to let them move, just one moves... How can I fix it? All nodes are completely the same except size and position...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just because nodes share the same name doesn't mean they share the same properties.  This is the same with people.  If I meet 2 people named John, and I shaved the first Johns head, it doesn't mean the second John is bald.

What you need to do is enumerate through all of the children with the same name.

In Sprite Kit, we have a method for that, called `enumerateChildNodes` and you would use it like this:

```
node.enumerateChildNodes(withName:"John")
{
  //[unowned self] Include this if you are using self to avoid a retain cycle

  node,stop in
  node.head = shaved
}
```